# real part of analytic function of fixed sign

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z)$ is analytic and satisfies $|(f(z))^2-1|<1$ on a non empty connected open set $U$ then prove that real part of $f$ is of fixed sign on $U$. 
Absolutely clueless on how to proceed. Can someone help me with hints in the direction I should proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there are $z_1\neq z_2\in U$ such that Re$\ f(z_1)<0$ and Re$\ f(z_2)>0$. Since $U$ is connected, there is a $z=(x,y)\in U$ such that Re$\ f(z)=0$. Then, with $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)=iv(x,y)$ we have $|-v(x,y)^2-1|=|1+v(x,y)^2|<1$ which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general fact about complex numbers: $|a-1|<1$ implies $\Re a >0$ (squaring the inequality we get $0\le |a|^2<2\Re a$).

In our case, we get $\Re f^2=(\Re f)^2-(\Im f)^2 >0$ so in particular $\Re f \ne 0$ and connectedness implies constant sign then.